# Sharepoint 2013 - Different background image at refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've added 9 backgrounds in my SiteAssets and I want them to randomly appear when the user clicks on any of the pages?

I've tried the following:

Before the DOCTYPE

```
<?php
$bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

In the head section or in the body section

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{
background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
}
-->
</style>
```

but it didn't work. I think it's because I'm missing the CSS tag for the background in Sharepoint.

Could you help with this?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: PHP? SharePoint does not speak php.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that. A bit of a newbie. Do you know how to do it without using php? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some simple JavaScript/jQuery to accomplish this.  Checkout this article: http://briancray.com/posts/simple-image-randomizer-jquery.  This is the JavaScript the article uses (modified for the body tag):

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

**EDIT**

Here is one way you can do it:

- Add a Content Editor Web Part to the page.
- With the cursor in the editor portion of the web part (where you would enter content), select Edit Source from the Format Text ribbon tab.  This will bring up a box to enter HTML.
- Add the following:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
  $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
  </script>
  ```

This is loading jQuery from Microsoft's CDN.  You can download the library and upload it to your SharePoint site if you want.  Then just update the src link to where it is on SharePoint.  Replace the image names with your images and replace the "images/" in the background-image property with the path to the images in SharePoint.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I tried adding it onto a script editor, but that didn't seem to work. Where should I apply this piece of code?

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded on the page?

Comment: Hi John, could you guide me on how to get it loading on the page? Which file or part do I have to modify?

Comment: Edited the answer with more details.

Comment: Hi John, did exactly what you said, but it didn't work. I've took some print screens which are now in the main question. Could you have a look? Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console? (In IE, open the F12 Developer Tools).

Comment: Nope, i don't see any errors.

Comment: In the F12 Developer Toolbar, hit the refresh icon to make sure it has the latest output from the page.  Then in the HTML tab, expand the code until you can select the body tag.  With the body tag selected, look on the right side and see if the background image was set.  (Just want to see if its getting set, but to the wrong URL, or something like that).

Comment: Hi John, I think you're right, it's getting set a different background picture. I've selected the current background from the Change the Look menu, should I remove the background image from there? Edited the main question with a picture.

Comment: Yes. Try that...

Comment: For some reason, when I went back to my content editor just now, the script code wasn't there anymore? That's strange.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late for you, but for anyone else who comes across this article you can try this link...

> [...] this is a quick example of how to randomly change the background image.
>   You’ll probably want to tidy it up for production (checking that
>   certain scripts are loaded, moving the CSS into a file, etc), but it
>   worked for our demo.
>
> First you’ll need to modify the master HTML page and add the following
>   to the `<head>` section…
>
> ```
> <!--MS:<style type="text/css">--> <!--
> .backOne{background-image:url('/images/img1.png')}
> .backTwo{background-image:url('/images/img2.png')}
> .backThree{background-image:url('/images/img3.png')}
> --> <!--ME: </style>—>
> ```
>
> Thanks to Eric Overfield at PixelMill for the way to add a style to
>   your HTML master page.
>
> Then add a bit of script to the end of the page, just before the
>   `</body>` tag…
>
> ```
> <script>   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("swapBodyImage");  
> function swapBodyImage(){   var r = Math.random() * 3;   var img =
> "backOne";   if (r > 2) img = "backTwo";   else if (r > 1) img =
> "backThree";   CSSUtil.AddClass(document.body, img);} </script>
> ```
>
> The script will then randomly choose one of your styles and so set the
>   background.

http://blog.thekid.me.uk/post/Random-background-body-images-images-in-SharePoint